# confluent schema registry authentication using clickhouse with kafka engine

Tags: apache-kafka, basic-authentication, apache-kafka-connect, clickhouse, confluent-schema-registry

I want to consume messages with AvroConfluent format from kafka topic and store them in a clickhouse table so i created a table with kafka engine and I entered my schema registry url in table settings, but the schema registry server needs basic authentication which I am not sure where and how should I put my user information. like kafka authentication configuration I tried putting my information in config.xml file for clickhouse-server but apparently it is not working

Comment: could you provide the xml-config, the error message, etc?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pass the user authentication in the schema registry URL in the table settings - `http://username:password@example.com`

```
format_avro_schema_registry_url = https://{api_key}:{api_secret}@{schema_registry_url};
```

Answer (score 0):

To define auth credentials it needs to:

1. open *config.xml*

```sh
sudo nano /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/config.xml
```

2. extend the *kafka*-element by required params:

```xml
<kafka>
    <security_protocol>sasl_plaintext</security_protocol>
    <sasl_mechanism>PLAIN</sasl_mechanism>
    <sasl_username>test</sasl_username>
    <sasl_password>test</sasl_password>
    <!-- .. -->
</kafka>
```

3. restart clickhouse service

```sh
sudo service clickhouse-server restart
```

See for details https://altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-kafka-engine-faq.

Comment: I have problem with confluent schema registry authentication not kafka